# How to keep the previous time in a form without updating to current time in a form

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii framework.
I have a form with the following field.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'CreatedDate'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'CreatedDate'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'CreatedDate'); ?>
</div>
```

I want this field to retain the same value which it had previously to be retained.
The database table which contains the above field has this value

```
|CreatedDate        | datetime     | YES  |
```

When I click on a submit button, this field gets updated to current time without retaining the previous datetime. 
How can I keep the previous time without updating to current time.

Comment: Where does the new time come from? What changes it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of what you trying to achieve but this might help:

```
echo $form->textField($model,'CreatedDate',array('readonly'=>'readonly'));
```